# GITLAB-CI in a specific branch name

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, branch, gitlab-ci

I would like to trigger the job when I am on a branch called RCT_release / XX.XX.XX
but I can not
I tried this:

```
send:
    stage: Copy_RCT
    environment:
        name: RCT
    script:
        - branch_name="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME|cut -d "_" -f1)"
        - echo $branch_name
    only:
        - pushes
    only:
        - /^RCT_release.*$/
```

Comment: Do you try to remove your first `only` with pushes ?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should try to allow only branches, except everything different from your regexp :

```
only: 
  - branches 
except:
  - ^(?!(RCT_release.*$)$).*$
```

This will allow only branches with an exception for everything except your `RCT_Release` branches.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Please try with my updated answer, with this regexp : `^(?!(RCT_release.*$)$).*$`

Comment: I think the problem comes from "/" :  RCT_release"/"00.00.00

Comment: I updated again, sorry.
Do you try with another branch with same pattern without "/" ?

Comment: I try with RCT_release01.01.01 
so the problem comes from special characters like "." and "/"

Comment: That's strange, it should match.